# How to get custom field image url of specific size

Tags: plugins, custom-field, attachments, post-meta

I have a "cmb2" custom field with `type->file`. and i use it to upload images.

**If i use:**

`echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_pf_photo1', 'medium' );`

i get the url of the full image (not the medium one).

How can i get the url of the 'medium' / 'thumbnail' and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `get_post_meta()` function can help to get the meta field but will not retrieve different size.

Assuming `_pf_photo1` embed the attachment id, you can do something like that:

```
// Note the "_id" suffix
$attachment_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_pf_photo1_id', true);
```

Last parameter for this function can not be 'medium',

Now,you can use `$attachment_id` with different function depending on what you really want to get (url, img element...):

```
$attachment_element = wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'medium' );
echo $attachment_element;
```

There is more ways to get details for attachment `wp_get_attachment_url()`, `wp_get_attachment_image_src` (that returns an array with url, width, height).

You will find more details to discover these functions [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url)

Hope it helps !

Comment: `$attachment_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_pf_photo1', true);` doesn't give me the "id". if i do `echo $attachment_id;` i get the full image url.

Comment: So, maybe, you will find an answer with this other question : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39387/how-can-i-get-a-different-image-size-if-all-i-have-is-the-link . Note that to work with image size easily, you maybe need to consider to save the attachment id instead of the link.

Comment: It seems that in "cmb" you have to add "_id" to the field key to get the id so it's: `get_post_meta($post->ID, '_pf_photo1_id', true);` now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can get the *ID* of the file with `_pf_photo1_id`, then it's easy to get any size URL:

```
$file_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_pf_photo1_id', true );

if ( $file_id )
    echo wp_get_attachment_image_url( $file_id, 'medium' );
```

Comment: `$file_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_pf_photo1_id', true );` doesn't give me the "id". if i do `echo $file_id;` i get the full image url.

Comment: Are you sure? [The documentation describes the `_id` suffix](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress/wiki/Field-Types#file)

Comment: It seems that in "cmb" you have to add "_id" to the field key to get the id so it's: `get_post_meta($post->ID, '_pf_photo1_id', true);` now it works. Thanks!

Comment: @Ben Are you serious? That is _literally_ what my answer was. And you accepted the other answer that doesn't even explain this.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't get you, but anyway i accepted the other answer because it's more detailed about the main subject of the question. did give your answer a plus one... sorry.

Comment: I've updated the other answer so that it's at least correct.

Comment: I don't understand why this isn't the accepted answer!